# Convert different object into single JSON string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to create json like this:

```
{  
   "classA":{  
      "A":"",
      "B":"",
      "C":""
   },
   "classB":{  
      "E":"",
      "A":"",
      "G":""
   },
   "classC":{  
      "A":"",
      "B":""
   },
   "classD":{  
      "A":""
   }
}
```

How to convert this type of json? I am using `Newtonsoft.Json`, however I currently convert it with a hard coded method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a wrapper class for all your objects and de/serialize the wrapper:

Use a tool like [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate the class structure:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public string E { get; set; }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string G { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}

public class ClassD
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}

public class Wrapper
{
    public ClassA classA { get; set; }
    public ClassB classB { get; set; }
    public ClassC classC { get; set; }
    public ClassD classD { get; set; }
}
```

After this you can deserialize it like that:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(json);
```

To serialize an existing object into a json string you can proceed like that:

```
var obj = new Wrapper();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Comment: can you please tell how to do it vice versa like how to accept same json in web api 2
@croxy

Comment: @UsmanAsif I'm not quite sure what you are asking for. What do you mean by *vice versa*? I already described both ways, how to serialize and how to deserialize. Do you want to send this json to a web api?

Comment: I want to accept same Json in web api 2 c sharp class @croxy

Comment: @UsmanAsif I'm no Web Api expert. But I think it should be enough having a Post method which accepts the wrapper object as parameter: `public void MyMethod(Wrapper data) { // Do something }`. The deserialization should be automatically handled by asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the newtonsoft library can't do that from a box.

You can make a class by your scheme and then serialize/deserialize it.

Comment: can you please tell how to do it vice versa like how to accept same json in web api 2